# Removing double new lines using awk/sed

Tags: file, unix, sed

Hey everyone.
I have a file full of data, each row consists of something similiar to "755545;45634;1244". Sometimes somewhere there can occur an unknown number of additional new lines, which I dont want.
Example:

```
256163;16816;1651
16156;165165;1165

15153;135135;15351
15153;1351;8



165;15313;153513
254;45;45
```

Desired output:

```
256163;16816;1651
16156;165165;1165    
15153;135135;15351
15153;1351;8
165;15313;153513
254;45;45
```

Can this be done easily with awk/sed utility in unix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer from @Luixv is correct if there are no whitespace on the "empty" lines.
If whitespace is present use this instead:

```
sed '/^[ \t]*$/d'
```

Thats an space before the \t within the brackets, i.e. [space\t]

If this doesn't work, you might have a problem with newlines. Do a:

```
$ file test_file
test_file: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

If you get the output above, convert the file to unix using:

```
$ dos2unix test_file
```

Comment: YES YES YES! Great! Exactly. Fully working afterwards thank you!

Comment: Also be careful if you're using files that came from windows.  If so you may need to match the ^M (the extra windows endline character) as well as spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 6):

sed '/^$/d'

Comment: Thx for reply. I tried but it seems it add one additional new line instead of deleting them..

Comment: well, I am trying it right now and it works. Then what I am assuming is that you don't have empty lines but sumething else (may be tabs, spaces?). Right a small test file and try it.

Comment: Hmm, thats interesting. I tried it with my example and its working. But I apply that on the main file it looks like its not working. Could it be because of the file size (about 250Mb of pure text!).

Comment: No, I don't think so. 
To look what is at the empty lines. If you are under a unix machine make an octal dumo (od <fileName>) in order to see if it is an empty line or not. Compare it with your test file

Comment: to look what is at the empty lines. If you are under a unix machine make an octal dumo (od <fileName>) in order to see if it is an empty line or not. Compare it with your test file.

Comment: I just dont get it. Those are empty lines! Ive hit enter to make few new lines in the main file and than apply this sed and it wasnt working. If I do the same with same chars in a different file (copy n pasted!) it wokrs... grrr

Comment: Solved. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -nre "s/([^$])/\1/p" input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/^[ ,\t]*$/!p' filename
```

Comment: Since unix consider space and tab as different characters i guesws we should mention both

Comment: (Fixed the tab escape. Escapes use backspaces. A forward space here is probably not what was intended. I guess this was a typo.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `ssed` super_sed if you do not have it installed, install it.

```
ssed -R -e '/(^$|\s)/ d' yourFile
```

or

```
cat yourFile| ssed -R -e '/(^$|\s)/ d'
```

Happy seding

PS: will work even if you have tabs or `\r \t \n` hence the `\s` in the ReqExp.

```
\r = Return Carriage
\n = New Line
\t = Tab
```